# Gradle sync failed: failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have installed Android 5.0 sdk 21 and have checked all the possible solutions but none of them worked for my case.
Im receiving the same error

**Gradle sync failed: failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.2
Consult IDE log for more details**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just open SDK Manager and install Build-tools 21.1.2. below is what you need to install:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that update build tool revision 21.1.2 in the SDK?
Let's open SDK manager to install this build tool version :)